# How do I get Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?

Tags: wireless, drivers, software-installation

It worked with the pre-installed Ubuntu, but after re-installing Ubuntu dual-boot with Windows 8.1, the WiFi is not working.

Is there a driver for this adapter that will work on Ubuntu 12.04?

Comment: Have you tried it? That card is showing up as certified in the database: - http://www.ubuntu.com/certification/catalog/component/pci/14c3:7630/ It should just work out of the box.

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/q/372858/20275

Answer (score 20):

A better solution is to install the driver using DKMS. This way you won't need to re-install it after kernel uprades. Do it this way:

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms build-essential
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
cd MT7630E/
sudo make dkms
```

Answer (score 18):

Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>), then run the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
cd MT7630E/
chmod +x install test uninstall
sudo ./install
```

Works like a charm for me (Asus TP300LD).

Comment: This works like a charm for me too, but it doesn't stick: maybe a week later I have to run all the process again. Do you know a way of doing it so I don't have to repeat the process every now and then? Thanks. (By the way, I'm on 14.04)

Comment: how do i install this wsithout wifi...

Comment: This solution will require to re-install the driver after each kernel upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

In my case (ubuntu desktop 16.04.4 LTS) this worked

Download release package from https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E/archive/release.zip

unzip the zip file and in the unzipped directory

```
sudo chmod +x install
sudo ./install
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Check this bug https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146 and mark it as affecting you if it wasn't fixed yet.
2. Install old 3.5 kernel (3.5.0-17 in my case)
3. Download https://github.com/anthonywong/mt7630 , edit hardcoded kernel versions, compile it and load the modules with the load.sh

P.S. Latest Unity will not work on 3.5 so you will have to install alternative DE.