# Wireless not working on Asus F552CL-SX049H

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, asus

I tried Ubuntu 14.04 live on my Asus F552CL-SX049H, and the wireless is not working.

Running `lspci` gives the following result:

```
[...]
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
[...]
```

`iwconfig` says "no wireless extensions."

`lshw -C network` shows no drivers bound to the Wireless Network Adapter.

The kernel version is `3.13.0-24-generic`.

Edit: the following is the output of [this script](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do), as requested by Wild Man in the comments.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

##### release #####

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel #####

Linux ubuntu 3.13.0-24-generic #46-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 10 19:11:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

##### lspci #####

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e074]
04:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:5289] (rev 01)

04:00.2 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 0a)
    Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device [1043:200f]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

##### lsusb #####

Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 04f2:b40a Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0489:e069 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 05e3:0727 Genesys Logic, Inc. microSD Reader/Writer
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) Flash Drive
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA Card Info #####

##### rfkill #####

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### iw reg get #####

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### interfaces #####

# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### iwconfig #####

##### route #####

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface

##### resolv.conf #####

##### nm-tool #####

NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        <MAC address removed>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off

##### NetworkManager.state #####

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf #####

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### iwlist #####

##### iwlist channel #####

##### lsmod #####

##### modinfo #####

##### modules #####

##### blacklist #####

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/fbdev-blacklist.conf]
blacklist arkfb
blacklist aty128fb
blacklist atyfb
blacklist radeonfb
blacklist cirrusfb
blacklist cyber2000fb
blacklist gx1fb
blacklist gxfb
blacklist kyrofb
blacklist matroxfb_base
blacklist mb862xxfb
blacklist neofb
blacklist nvidiafb
blacklist pm2fb
blacklist pm3fb
blacklist s3fb
blacklist savagefb
blacklist sisfb
blacklist tdfxfb
blacklist tridentfb
blacklist viafb
blacklist vt8623fb

##### udev rules #####

# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC address removed>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #####

[   20.030173] psmouse serio4: elantech: assuming hardware version 4 (with firmware version 0x361f03)

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Have you tried installing proprietary drivers?

Comment: No. Any suggestions? However, at the moment I'm just using the live.

Comment: Open the proprietary driver manager. Just type in 'driver' into the dash, you should see it.

Comment: No network-related driver appears.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Comment: I've edited the question with the output of the script.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)