# MT7630e ralink wireless driver for ubuntu not available!

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04

I installed ubuntu 14 but my wireless is not working !
 I googled for driver but i cant found anything .

please help guys!

Comment: Start by identifying the wireless device/chip you are using. You may not need driver. If USB, output from **`lsusb`** that changes when the device is attached. If inbuilt, look as content of **`sudo lshw`**.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nifty bit of software called Ndiswrapper to utilize a Windows wifi driver on Ubuntu.

Just follow this awesome Ubuntu help doc, and you'll be set:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/Ndiswrapper

Comment: I tried Ndiswrapper but not working .
I googled and found that this is bug since Ubuntu 12 and not resolved yet!

Comment: Huh, well it has been a long time since I have had to use Ndiswrapper. Fortunately, my wifi has been supported out of the box. I don't think I can fix the bug, but I would like to see the bug report if you have a link to it.

Comment: [Here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146) is the bug

Comment: Well that really sucks. In the mean time, I would purchase a USB wifi dongle.