# wlan0 not showing up.... MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless

Tags: wireless, 14.04

here is what when I type `ifconfig`

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr a0:48:1c:0a:47:f3  
          inet addr:192.168.25.186  Bcast:192.168.25.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a248:1cff:fe0a:47f3/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:41528 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:16348 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:23075826 (23.0 MB)  TX bytes:2128515 (2.1 MB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:1951 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1951 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:189033 (189.0 KB)  TX bytes:189033 (189.0 KB)
```

on typing `lspci -nnk`

```
00:00.0 Host bridge [0600]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller [8086:0a04] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller [8086:0a0c] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB xHCI HC [8086:9c31] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller [0780]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HECI #0 [8086:9c3a] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1b.0 Audio device [0403]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP HD Audio Controller [8086:9c20] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 1 [8086:9c10] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 2 [8086:9c12] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3 [8086:9c14] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 4 [8086:9c16] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.4 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 5 [8086:9c18] (rev e4)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller [0c03]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP USB EHCI #1 [8086:9c26] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge [0601]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP LPC Controller [8086:9c43] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller [0106]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] [8086:9c03] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus [0c05]: Intel Corporation Lynx Point-LP SMBus Controller [8086:9c22] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:197c]
09:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller [10ec:8136] (rev 08)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:2164]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169
0a:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M] [1002:6660] (rev ff)
    Kernel driver in use: radeon
```

Comment: [Bug #1220146 - Need support for new Ralink Wifi card - Mediatek 7630](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a known issue and there are instructions to install manually a driver at 
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146/comments/125

Comment: i downloaded driver manually from the link you specified but not able to copy it to lib/firmware

Comment: copying done but not able to locate rt2x00 directory @user4124

Comment: took help of my frnd and now thats done (y)... :) :) :) ...and at ;last thanks a lot @user 4124

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, the [link above](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146/comments/125) works fine, if the error "I do not know how to handle rt2x00 ..." appears while trying

```
sudo dkms add –m rt2x00 –v VV
sudo dkms build –m rt2x00 –v VV
sudo dkms install –m rt2x00 –v VV
sudo dkms install –m rt2x00 –v VV --force
```

Try instead:

```
sudo dkms add rt2x00/VV
sudo dkms build rt2x00/VV
sudo dkms install rt2x00/VV
sudo dkms install rt2x00/VV --force
```

At least it worked for me.