# wi fi not showing in newly installed ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking, wireless, mediatek

I just installed ubuntu 14.04, but I found no wifi on it. I run command:

```
lspci | grep "Network"
```

and got the output :

```
03.00.0Network controller: MEDIATEC Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network  Adapter
```

run command:

lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

and got output:

```
03.00.0 Network Controller [0280]:MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
      Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard  Company Device [103c:197c]
```

what should I do now?

How to enable wifi in Ubuntu 14.04?

TIA

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [wlan0 not showing up.... MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless](http://askubuntu.com/questions/504718/wlan0-not-showing-up-mediatek-corp-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wireless)

Comment: i got the answer here http://askubuntu.com/a/621804/437587  but it uninstalled wireless driver from windows, then i had to reinstall it on my window.

Comment: This can not be the case. Installing something to linux cannot uninstall anything from Windows.

Comment: i don't know but in device manager i didn't find any wireless driver/adapter found no wireless option in my laptop,then i downloaded wifi driver and installed it and everything is fine now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)