# no wireless connection on ubuntu 14.04 of my ASUS laptop TP500LA-CJ059H with Wireless: 802.11b/g/n

Tags: wireless, networking

Here are the information about wireless on my laptop.

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 21 Oct 2014 15:20 WST +0800

Booted last: 21 Oct 2014 15:01 WST +0800

Script from: 20 Sep 2014 23:04 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty

##### kernel ############################

Linux 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:28:38 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

02:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:0123]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e  Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. Device [105b:e074]

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0461:4d22 Primax Electronics, Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0457:10c1 Silicon Integrated Systems Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 13d3:5656 IMC Networks 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0489:e069 Foxconn / Hon Hai 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### lsmod #############################

asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
video                  19476  2 i915,asus_wmi
wmi                    19177  1 asus_wmi

##### interfaces ########################

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>  
          inet addr:202.8.37.243  Bcast:202.8.37.255  Mask:255.255.255.128
          inet6 addr: fe80::7a24:afff:feda:8f73/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:43582 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:11308 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:37750253 (37.7 MB)  TX bytes:1948056 (1.9 MB)

##### iwconfig ##########################

eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         202.8.37.129    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
202.8.37.128    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.128 U     1      0        0 eth0

##### resolv.conf #######################

nameserver 127.0.1.1
search ivec.org pawsey.ivec.org gw.pawsey.ivec.org

##### nm-tool ###########################

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        <MAC 'eth0' [IF]>

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           1000 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         202.8.37.243
    Prefix:          25 (255.255.255.128)
    Gateway:         202.8.37.129

    DNS:             192.65.130.136
    DNS:             202.158.207.1

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true
WimaxEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager.conf ###############

[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile,ofono
dns=dnsmasq

[ifupdown]
managed=false

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Australia/Perth (based on set time zone)

country 00:
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (6, 20)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 40), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (6, 20), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5170 - 5250 @ 160), (6, 20), PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5250 - 5330 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (6, 20), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN, NO-IBSS

##### iwlist channels ###################

eth0      no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

lp
rtc

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

[/etc/modprobe.d/mlx4.conf]
softdep mlx4_core post: mlx4_en

##### rc.local ##########################

exit 0

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

[/etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules]
# PCI device 0x10ec:0x8168 (r8169)
SUBSYSTEM=="net", ACTION=="add", DRIVERS=="?*", ATTR{address}=="<MAC 'eth0' [IF]>", ATTR{dev_id}=="0x0", ATTR{type}=="1", KERNEL=="eth*", NAME="eth0"

##### dmesg #############################

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: It is currently an open bug for the [0280] devices: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146

Comment: And possible proprietary solution?: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146/comments/125

Comment: Problem solved by following the second link. Many thanks, @jmunsch

Comment: But the wireless connection is not stable. It often interrupts without any notice. I am sure this is not caused by the wireless provider.

Comment: Very Cool. And also can you update your question title to include the model of computer you are using? And if you choose to Follow that bug for updates, it may be resolved sometime in the future.

Comment: Details of my laptop is added in the title. The wireless connection becomes stable now though I do not make any more changes. Thanks again. @jmunsch

Comment: If you would also like, you could answer your own question with the exact steps that you followed. Especially if it solved your problem. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)