# ASUS X550C wifi

Tags: 14.04, wireless, networking, asus

There is a lot of similar problems, but this one is a bit different. I have no *phy0: Wireless LAN*

Ubuntu: 14.04.1

**sudo rfkill list all**

```
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

When I plug in an external wifi usb adapter from TP-Link, I got also

```
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

and my wifi works. But I dont know why my wifi doesnt work without this adapter.

**lsmod**

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ctr                    13049  0 
ccm                    17773  0 
arc4                   12608  0 
ath9k_htc              95963  0 
ath9k_common           13551  1 ath9k_htc
ath9k_hw              453856  2 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc
ath                    28698  3 ath9k_common,ath9k_htc,ath9k_hw
mac80211              630653  1 ath9k_htc
cfg80211              484040  3 ath,mac80211,ath9k_htc
bnep                   19624  2 
rfcomm                 69160  0 
bluetooth             391136  10 bnep,rfcomm
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     46368  1 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    65580  1 
uvcvideo               80885  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         40664  1 uvcvideo
videodev              134688  2 uvcvideo,videobuf2_core
asus_nb_wmi            16990  0 
asus_wmi               24191  1 asus_nb_wmi
sparse_keymap          13948  1 asus_wmi
intel_rapl             18773  0 
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    14205  0 
intel_powerclamp       14705  0 
coretemp               13435  0 
kvm_intel             143187  0 
kvm                   455835  1 kvm_intel
snd_hda_intel          56451  3 
snd_hda_codec         192906  3 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13602  1 snd_hda_codec
crct10dif_pclmul       14289  0 
crc32_pclmul           13113  0 
snd_pcm               102099  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_page_alloc         18710  2 snd_pcm,snd_hda_intel
ghash_clmulni_intel    13216  0 
cryptd                 20359  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            30144  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61560  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
joydev                 17381  0 
serio_raw              13462  0 
snd_seq_device         14497  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              29482  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
lpc_ich                21080  0 
snd                    69322  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device,snd_seq_midi
rtsx_pci_ms            18151  0 
memstick               16966  1 rtsx_pci_ms
soundcore              12680  1 snd
mei_me                 18627  0 
mei                    82276  1 mei_me
i915                  784207  4 
wmi                    19177  1 asus_wmi
drm_kms_helper         55071  1 i915
video                  19476  2 i915,asus_wmi
drm                   303102  5 i915,drm_kms_helper
i2c_algo_bit           13413  1 i915
mac_hid                13205  0 
parport_pc             32701  0 
ppdev                  17671  0 
lp                     17759  0 
parport                42348  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
nls_iso8859_1          12713  1 
hid_generic            12548  0 
usbhid                 52659  0 
hid                   106148  2 hid_generic,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         23274  0 
r8169                  67581  0 
psmouse               106714  0 
rtsx_pci               46202  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
ahci                   25819  3 
mii                    13934  1 r8169
libahci                32716  1 ahci
```

*/etc/modprobe.d/asus.conf* is empty

```
blacklist asus_nb_wmi
```

doesnt work.

**lspci -nn | grep 0280**

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
```

Comment: I suspect that your internal wireless is this: "0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN" It may be that it lacks a driver or that the driver isn't loading. Please edit your question to add details of your internal device from: lspci -nn | grep 0280 Thanks.

Comment: I just added it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)

Answer (score 0):

Your device does indeed lack a driver. Please get a temporary internet connection and open a terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic build-essential git
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/mt7630.git
cd mt7630
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
```

Let us know about any errors or if you get stuck. We will probably have one additional step.

Unfortunately, on my Ubuntu 14.10 system, I also get the 'Unknown symbol in module, or unknown parameter' error. Consulting the github page shows this comment from the developer:

> since I don't have time and hardware so please don't expect any
>   improvement.

I regret that I know of no way currently to get this device working correctly. For now, I suggest you continue to use the USB.

Comment: I got problem with last command.

martin@martin-X550CA:~/mt7630$ sudo modprobe rt2800pci
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'rt2800pci': Invalid argument

Comment: Please try a reboot and see if it loaded automatically: lsmod | grep rt2

Comment: lsmod | grep rt2

rt2x00lib              51721  0 

mac80211              630653  2 rt2x00lib,ath9k_htc

cfg80211              484040  4 ath,mac80211,rt2x00lib,ath9k_htc

Comment: Now detach the USB and see if the internal is working: iwconfig.

Comment: iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

Comment: Look for clues: dmesg | grep rt2. It may be lengthy, so paste it here and give us the link in your response: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/9595251/

Comment: May I assume that the reboot was with the USB and therefore its possibly conflicting drivers removed?

Comment: I unplugged USB and then rebooted

Comment: Please see my edit above.