# Ubuntu doesn't see WIFI ! ASUS-K500CC

Tags: wireless, asus

I know there were a lot of similar cases and I've tried to follow some of the answers on the web but none of them are working, or are causing more errors along the way.

I bought new ASUS -K500CC, install ubuntu 14.10 (then replace to 14.04) but there are no options were to connect to wifi. My router is working and all other devices are seeing it.

Here is some information, which can help you to help me.

```
~$ rfkill list all 
0: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
1: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no

~$ iwlist scan
eth0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

~$ lspci | grep Network
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
```

Please help :((

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Download the driver for the MT7630e controller from [this](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796) page
2. In a terminal, `cd ~/Downloads; unzip MT7630E-master.zip; cd MT7630E-master; sudo chmod +x install.sh` (you will be prompted for `sudo` password), then `./install.sh`
3. Reboot

At this point the controller should be hard-blocked every time the system boots up, requiring to suspend to RAM and to resume in order to unblock it; to fix this:

1. In a terminal: `echo "options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb.conf` (you will be prompted for `sudo` password)
2. Reboot

If this doesn't prevent the controller from being hard-blocked after boot, try this:

1. In a terminal: `sudo gedit /etc/modprobe.d/asus_nb.conf`
2. Replace `4` with `1` in this line: `options asus_nb_wmi wapf=4`
3. Save
4. Exit
5. Reboot

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Unfortunately at the step ./install.sh I get this error .. (
 
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module /lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko: File exists

What I need to to with this ?

Comment: @AramKhachatryan That shouldn't be a problem, since i had the same error (along with many others). Have you rebooted and checked if the wifi is now available? Keep in mind that after such reboot the chip might still be hard-blocked, so try to suspend to RAM and to resume, and if that activates the chip follow the tutorial from that point

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/users/380067/kos Hi, please can you help me ? :(( I upgrade ubuntu to 14.10 and this steps dont give solution for my problem (

Comment: @AramKhachatryan Unfortunately i don't know what else to suggest you, the instructions above worked for me on Ubuntu 14.04. What happens exactly?