# WIFI Mediatek MT7630 not working on ubuntu 14,04, need help

Tags: wireless, laptop

My laptop asus x550cc has a wifi adapter mediatek MT7630E and it doesn't work on ubuntu. In the Internet there are drivers, but the install doesn't work, comes up with error. Need help with

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working)

Answer (score 0):

I had an asus with this mediatek 7630 wifi problem

I used this:

http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796

And it helps....