# Wifi not working on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (Dual Boot). (windows 8)

Tags: 14.04

I installed ubuntu 14.04 LTS in windows 8 hp-pavilion-15 model. But after that wifi not working in Ubuntu. But in windows 8 it is working fine.
when i run "lshw -C network" in terminal it showing like this.please give me a solution... thank you in advance

```
narasimha@narasimha-HP-Pavilion-15-Notebook-PC:~$ lshw -C network<br>
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.<br>
*-network UNCLAIMED<br>
description: Network controller<br>
product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter<br>
vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.<br>
physical id: 0<br>
bus info: pci@000:08:00.0<br>
version: 00<br>
width: 32 bits<br>
clock: 33MHz<br>
capabilities: cap_list<br>
configuration: latency=0<br>
resources: memory:c2600000-c26fffff<br>
*-network<br>
description: Ethernet interface<br>
product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller<br>
vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.<br>
physical id: 0<br>
bus info: pci@0000:09:00.0<br>
logical name: eth0<br>
version: 08<br>
serial: a0:48:1c:12:7d:97<br>
size: 10Mbit/s<br>
capacity: 100Mbit/s<br>
width: 64 bits<br>
clock: 33MHz<br>
capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt<br>
10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation<br>
configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 <br>driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-2_0.0.1 04/23/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s resources: irq:42 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c2504000-c2504fff memory:c2500000-c2503fff WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Comment: Similar to https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working

Comment: Please have a look at https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/593848/254422

Answer (score -1):

I would back-up everything. Do a clean install -  Run Ubuntu as the primary and then use Oracle virtual machine to host Win 8

Comment: **  note:  you will have better control over the hardware/drivers

Comment: This doesn't provide any help the the OP, reinstalling because the wifi wasn't detected isn't a answer...

Comment: Was just a suggestion..  When you dual boot with windows;  most of the time you will find that it can be problematic.  you can run down a long list all day on as to why the WIFI is not working.. could be many of reasons. I am just suggesting an easier solution and to avoid additional issues.