# MT7630E wifi fix not working after kernel update

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel

I have an ASUS K555L and it comes with a Mediatek MT7630E WiFi adapter which doesn't work out-of-the-box in Ubuntu. After looking in this very same website, [I found a fix that worked](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working), but I had to re-install it after almost every software update.

But now, after a kernel update (linux headers 4.2.0-42generic), this fix doesn't work. It throws the following error:

modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7630e': Required key not available

So, is there a way of fixing the fix?, is there a way to revert to my old linux headers?

Comment: So, just disabling the secure boot would do the trick. Are there any drawbacks in doing that?

Comment: Yes, it will fix it. There are no drawbacks IMO, since Secure Boot is useless. I also wrote an answer [there](http://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-a-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working) how to install the driver a way that you won't need to re-install it every time.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/a/804519/167850

Comment: Works like a charm. Feel free to post it as an answer, I'll select it inmediately.

Comment: There is no need. You can upvote the other answer if you like it.