# Problem with Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi adapter

Tags: networking, wireless, asus, mediatek

When I installed Ubuntu I realized that I cannot connect to my home Wi-Fi at all, though wired connection worked perfectly. After a bit of googling I followed [these](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796) instructions and it worked!

However, now my notebook uses my Wi-Fi for 5 minutes maximum. After that connection is lost. I need to reconnect again by switching off and on *Enable Wi-Fi* panel.

There was not such problem in Windows and all my devices works well with this wireless network.

If I should attach some output results from Terminal, please let me know, as
I really do not know which commands to run.

UPDATE: [wireless info](//paste.ubuntu.com/23056213/)

I'm using:

- Asus X550C
- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS

Comment: When exactly did you download the zip archive with the source code and installer? It may be worth to try a newer or older release. It would also be easier if you installed the driver with `sudo make dkms` instead of `./install` (requires the `dmks` package but re-compiles the driver for every newly installed kernel).

Comment: @DavidFoerster It was a week ago, when I installed drivers again after OS update as they were lost. Hmm. the `dkms` does not work. However, I followed [these](https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796) instructions, but replaced last string with `sudo make dkms`. [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/23058157/) is what I got. Maybe I should use `--force` flag on that?

Comment: No, I don't think you should try `--force`. The messages mean that the driver is already included in Ubuntu's stock kernel and you shouldn't need to install any additional driver for that device.

Comment: Hi @Z.Zorg, did you solve your problem? I have the same issue. [This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working) is related, but as somebody commented there, I have to repeat the process every now and then :/