# can't connect to internet even by wire(could before)

Tags: wireless, internet, ethernet

I've got a problem on my laptop, I had internet and wi fi all the time on it, now connections are saved but laptop isnt connecting to any internet even by using the direct wire (router is working 100%). The connection kinda just dissapeared. What to do?

Output of `ifconfig -a` command:

```
lo      link encap: local loopback. 
        Int addr:127.0.0.1 mask 255.0.0.0. 
        Inet6 add::1/128 Scope:Host. 
        UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:65536 Metric: 1.
        RX packets:10756 errors:0 dropped: 0 overruns:0 frame:0. 
        TX packets:10756 errors:0 dropped: 0 overruns:0 Carrier:0. 
        Collisions 0 txquelelen:1. Rx bytes 795840 tx bytes 795840
```

`lspci` shows that Ethernet card is connected. `lsmod | grep e100` shows that `e100` module is loaded (See below picture):
[image]

Output of

```
cat /etc/modules; grep [[:alnum:]] /etc/modprobe.d/* | grep r8169:
```

/etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.

This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
 at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with "#" are ignored.

b43
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# map the specific PCI IDs instead of blacklisting the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:# to blacklist the whole r8169 module
/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf:#blacklist r8169

,
But found another problem, when I entered the site (a normal one), It says  that the connection is not private and there is possibility of hackers stealing my password.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; the entire conversation that was taking place here has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49263/discussion-on-question-by-alex-cant-connect-to-internet-even-by-wirecould-befo).

Answer (score 0):

You installed Ubuntu package `r8168-dkms` and that changed alias ID's to keep the r8169 driver from loading.  You should be able to fix by executing the following command in terminal

```
sudo apt-get remove r8168-dkms
```

Reboot

Comment: This package has not been instaled. I've wired connection but not wi fi conn, what can be this caused by?

Comment: I wonder why this file was found `/etc/modprobe.d/r8168-dkms.conf` see http://askubuntu.com/a/804519/300665 for wifi