# How to enable Mediatek MT7630 Wifi Adapter on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, connection

(**First time using Ubuntu**) I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on 16GB USB.

With the command *lspci* , I found that I have *Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter* on my *HP Pavilion 15-n004tx Notebook PC.*

It was not shown in the network drop-down list from Menu bar.

After using the instructions from  [this askubuntu link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working), now MEDIATEK MT7630 is shown in network list, but disconnected.

Can this adapter be used on my laptop. If yes, what else should I do to make it work ?

I am using a USB wifi adapter for now. But if I remove this USB wifi adapter, the internal Wifi adapter (MEDIATEK MT7630) is not working.

`lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

```
08:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
    DeviceName: Mediatek WLAN Mediatek Civic MT7630E bgn 1x1 + BT 4 LE PCIe+USB HMCWW
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [103c:197c]    
    Kernel driver in use: mt7630e
    Kernel modules: mt7630e


0: hci0: Bluetooth 
   Soft blocked: no
   Hard blocked: no

1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

The MEDIATEK MT7630 adapter is present only if I connect a USB wifi adapter.

Why is MT7630 adapter depending on external USB wifi adapter ?

---

**Edit : The solution given [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working) works for me.** **Wifi is working now**.

---

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: Please post terminal output as text, not as a screenshot. What do you mean "disconnected"? Connect it to some wireless network. Reboot first, maybe NM needs a restart.

Comment: I have restarted the system.. but problem is not solved. I have added two screen grabs.

Comment: It is not depending on the external adapter. It just doesn't work. I have no answer.

Comment: driver mt7680e is for the bluetooth, you need MT7680e for the wifi.

Comment: According to the link that I have mentioned, MT7630e is driver for mediatek MT7630E Wifi + Bluetooth combo chip .

Comment: It is the correct driver. What does `dmesg | grep mt` show?

Comment: Okay.... so i reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 and followed the same instructions... now wifi is working... Bluetooth is not working but for now my problem is solved... thanks @Pilot6.