# I can not get my wireless connection to work (and the usual solutions are not working)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

I have just installed the updated version of ubuntu and I want to get my wireless to work. I have been looking for ways to install updated drivers and I found 2 ways:

1- This first one told me to go on "additional drivers" and install the drivers there. Well, the only drivers there are not related to wireless and are already installed, so this way was not helping.

2-This second way required me to go on the terminal and type this command: "lspci -nn -d 14e4". This was suppose to show me the kind of wifi card I had  ( at least that is what I understood). But it doesn't show anything at all, it justs opens a new line. I have tried different variations of this command and none work. And since every video/site I consulted required this first step i can not go any further on this second way.

Sorry if it is a stupid mistake, but I have been trying to get this to work for long hours now and I just find new errors.

Thank you for your attention

Comment: How about: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: This appears. I am not sure if it shows my wifi card name. Does it show? Sorry for the probably dumb questions.



"03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [14c3:7630]
 Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter [105b:e084]
04:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GK208M [GeForce 920M] [10de:1299] (rev a1)
 Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK208M [GeForce 920M] [1043:1a6d]
"

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working It may or may not work depending on your exact Ubuntu version. Please try it and tell us if you have any errors.

Comment: I tried the first answer on that post and gives me this error: "modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'mt7630e': Required key not available".

Comment: The second answer on that post gave me this error on the second command: "fatal: destination path 'MT7630E' already exists and is not an empty directory." I wrote the other 2 commands anyway and, the first time i tried it it did some things but didn't solve the problem. The second time I ran all the 4 commands again, it showed this error in the last command(i guess because i had already done it once): "Error! DKMS tree already contains: mt7630e-2.1.0
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
Makefile:29: recipe for target 'dkms' failed
make: *** [dkms] Error 3".

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to fix my problem, thanks to chili555 I was able to find the name of my wifi card. Then I went to this site "https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1796" and followed the instructions. ATTENTION, you have to disable secure boot control before you do it or else it wont work.

Thank you so much for your help chili555.