# How do I get Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working for ASUS TP500LA

Tags: 12.04, wireless, make, adapter

I tried these commands::

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/neurobin/MT7630E.git
cd MT7630E/
chmod +x install test uninstall
sudo ./install
```

They can be found in [How do I get Mediatek MT7630E 802.11bgn Wi-Fi Adapter working?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377050/how-do-i-get-mediatek-mt7630e-802-11bgn-wi-fi-adapter-working),
but when I try to run `sudo ./install`, I get this error message:

```
make -C /lib/modules/4.15.0-29-generic/build M=/home/sivarama/MT7630E/rt2x00 modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
arch/x86/Makefile:156: CONFIG_X86_X32 enabled but no binutils support
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: gcc: command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 27: gcc: command not found
make[1]: gcc: Command not found
Makefile:976: "Cannot use CONFIG_STACK_VALIDATION=y, please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel"
  CC [M]  /home/sivarama/MT7630E/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o
/bin/sh: 1: gcc: not found
scripts/Makefile.build:332: recipe for target '/home/sivarama/MT7630E/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/sivarama/MT7630E/rt2x00/rt2x00dev.o] Error 127
Makefile:1552: recipe for target '_module_/home/sivarama/MT7630E/rt2x00' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/sivarama/MT7630E/rt2x00] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.15.0-29-generic'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Have you tried what your error message suggests please install libelf-dev, libelf-devel or elfutils-libelf-devel if you can't find a specific package then try running sudo apt-cache search "package"

Comment: Also install gcc because you also have a message saying gcc: not found

Comment: i installed ubuntu 18.04.1

Comment: Please install *build-essential* and try again.

Comment: i tried what the error message suggested, thanks for the info, it worked.